# Flutter WillPopScope with back key not working?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have an issue with WillPopScope.
I have an tutorial screen, it show when start app and click in side menu (when login success).
When start app, i click back key and it working, but when login and go to main view -> click side menu to show tutorial screen. I click back key but nothing happen (i want when click back key, it pop screen to main view like Navigator.pop(context)). 
So what is my problem? Thank you very much!
My code

```
return WillPopScope ( onWillPop: () async { return await viewModel.isExitApp(); },
```

Comment: You are navigating with Navigator.push or pushReplacment?

Comment: @AhmadRaza I used Navigator.pushNamed

Comment: then why you need WillPopScope if you just want to pop the screen back button will pop the current screen from stack

Answer (score -1):

You can easily pop screen to main view like this :

```
onWillPop: () async {
    return await Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: Wrong code guy, please check again